# Post multiple jquery with ajax to python

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax

my question: I'm trying to post multiple data using ajax request. But I don't get anything back from python script. I get a error from console, it says:

`data: { serializedData1, serializedData }

error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,`

But if I remove the `,` I will get more and more errors syntax errors.
If I edit the javascript like this: `data: serializedData1` it wil work but it isn't what I want.

```
var valueID = $(this).parent().parent().find(".inputLiveID")// this is the id I want
var serializedData1 = valueID.serialize()
var $form = $(this); // I want this value too
var serializedData = $form.serialize();

request = $.ajax({
    url: "/accounts/editnad/",
    type: "post",
    data: { serializedData1, serializedData }
});

request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
    console.log(response)
});

request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    console.error(
         "The following error occured: "+
                textStatus, errorThrown
        );
 });
```

python script:

```
def editnad(updatenad):
    result = False
    updid = updatenad.POST.get("newid")
    newnr = updatenad.POST.get("nadcodenr")
    newbesch = updatenad.POST.get("nadbeschikbaar")

    return HttpResponse(updid,newnr)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass name/value pairs in your ajax call, for example

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'myScript.py',
    data: {form1: serializedData1, form2: serializedData},
    success: function(response) {
        //do something with response
    }
});
```

Then in the python

```
updid = udatenad.POST.get('form1').updid
```

You'll also note I didn't assign the ajax call to a variable, I used a success callback instead. If you want to use a promise you can assign it, and then use resolution/broken callbacks. Guess I'm old school.

Comment: jQuery Ajax calls have returned a [jqXHR object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) which implements the promise interface since version 1.5, which is quite a few versions ago now.

Comment: You're right, I'm wrong. I usually just recommend callbacks because they're easier for most to understand and because jQuery's promises aren't quite the same as A+ compliant ones. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You define an array in JS with `[]`, not `{}`.

```
data: [ serializedData1, serializedData ]
```

Comment: What do I need to change in the python script so I can read the value of data array/list ?